Repeating validations on DTO's
I have recently started learning Asp.net core. I came across DTO's concept. I am using Attributes for validation. I have read online that validation on DTO's is considered common/good practice on addition to the model of course. However I see myself in most of the cases just copying and pasting the validation on the model to the DTO's. This is a violation of the DRY principle and this could be really messy when we have multiple  DTO's for a model.
1- How can we avoid duplicate validation ? What design pattern we can follow to insure "DRY code" ?
2- Is there a way to avoid duplication with the utilization of Attributes for example: grouping a set of attributes under name PasswordValidation and reuse that anywhere ? because I don't want to get into implementing that logic of the validation myself and benefit from other features like ModelState (if possible).

Hi @Mohammad Alshareef, You can create custom validation attributes that encapsulate a set of validation rules and apply them to your properties in both models and DTOs. Another approach, you can use libraries like FluentValidation to separate validation logic from your models and DTOs, making it more maintainable and reusable.
